# Cannot place w, a, s and d keycodes all together into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

please forgive me if my english isnt quite good, it is not my first language, sorry.

i noticed something when i tried to place the keycodes of these characters: w,a,s and d into an array. it seems that i can only place a combination of 3 of these characters, sometimes only 2 will register, when all 4 keyboard keys are pressed.
my array looks like this:
    game.keySlots = [0, 0, 0, 0];

a key is placed into an array everytime this event occurs:

```
$(this).keydown(function(e) {
    directionalMovements(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which, e.type);
});

$(this).keyup(function(e) {
    directionalMovements(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which, e.type);
});
```

this is how the function looks:

```
function directionalMovementsPlayer(offendingKey, eventType) {
    if (offendingKey == 87 || offendingKey == 83 || offendingKey == 65 || offendingKey == 68) {
        if (eventType == "keydown") {
            if (offendingKey != game.keySlots[0]) {
                for (count = 3; count > 0; count--) {
                    game.keySlots[count] = game.keySlots[count - 1];
                }       

                game.keySlots[0] = offendingKey;
            }
        } else {
            var keyLoc;

            for (count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
                if (offendingKey == game.keySlots[count]) {
                    keyLoc = count;
                }
            }

            game.keySlots[3] = 0;

            for (i = keyLoc; i < 3; i++) {
                game.keySlots[i] = game.keySlots[i + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code can actually do what i want it to do, im just curious why i cant place all 4 keys inside the array at a single point in time. i know there are other ways to capture keys, i just wanted experiment with this one. sorry if it looks very silly.hehe

Comment: Are you sure that the keys are in fact registering? I'm not sure if it's an OS or keyboard limitation, but a common problem is that you are limited to 3 keys down, and any more simply won't be processed.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle if anyone wants to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/jsjdjr14/  I too suspect that the keys are simply not registerung. I can place all 4 keys inside of the array when using my laptop keyboard and my external keyboard at once. I suspect that it would work with a single keyboard if I had a keyboard supporting n-key rollover.

Comment: it can accommodate 4 keys if, say, i swap "s" with a "p" or something where the array now has like w,a,d and p together. but not all the 4 mentioned keys above. also i noticed that the order in which you place the keys have something to do with it. for example, i type in 'd' and then 'w' respectively, and keep pressing them then typing in 's' to make them 3 keys being pressed down at the same time; it will not register the 's', making the number of keys caught by the array to be only 2. however, if i type in 'a' right after 'w', it will register; making the array capture 3 simultaneous inputs.

Comment: @Kendall Frey, Patrick Huy, thank you guys!